# Wait for getAuthToken Intent Result within a Service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-authenticator

First, the motivation:

I'm building an app that could benefit from, but does not absolutely require, Android services obtained via the `AccountManager`. That being the case, I've built my app without the `GET_ACCOUNTS` and `USE_CREDENTIALS` permissions, opting instead to build a `Service` plugin for authorization, which the user can optionally install. Now, this plugin works entirely as intended except for one glaring issue: I can start the `Intent` returned from `getAuthToken(...)` that asks for initial authorization, but I cannot wait for it to complete.

So, now that it is known why I want to call `getAuthToken(...)` from a `Service` instead of an `Activity`, does anyone know how I can wait for the authorization `Intent` to complete before returning a token? Basically, in the code below, does anyone know how to hold off on returning `token` until `authIntent` completes?

```
...
AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> accountManagerFuture;
accountManagerFuture = accountManager.getAuthToken(accounts[0], "android", true, null, null);
Bundle authTokenBundle = accountManagerFuture.getResult();
if (authTokenBundle.containsKey(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN))
    token = authTokenBundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN).toString();
else if (authTokenBundle.containsKey(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT)) {
    Intent authIntent = (Intent) authTokenBundle.getParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT);
    authIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(authIntent);
    ...
    // I know that I wouldn't set token here; this is just to emphasize
    // that I want to set it after authIntent completes
    token = ???
}
```

Also, if it's of any use to know, the code above is located within an `AsyncTask`. It'd be ugly, but maybe I could poll `getAuthToken(...)` until it no longer returns an `Intent`? I have to believe there's a better solution than that, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the best answer, I'm sure, but I think it should work for my specific situation. Namely, the following constraints apply:

1. The `Service` plugin is designed only to interface with the parent app.
2. The parent app will not continuously invoke the plugin.
3. The authorization `Intent` returned by `getAuthToken(...)` is invoked infrequently (probably only one time).
4. Once the `Intent` from `getAuthToken(...)` is run, subsequent calls will return either a valid token (if the user granted authority) or an invalid token (if the user didn't grant authority).
5. The parent app is paused while the authorization prompt is present.

Given all of the above, I think that I can call `unbindService(...)` in `onPause()` of the parent app when the authorization prompt takes the focus. After the authorization prompt completes, I can then call `bindService(...)` in `onResume()`, and then invoke the task associated with `getAuthToken(...)` a subsequent time. At that time, since the authorization prompt will have already been applied (assuming normal user interaction), the parent app will get the (valid or invalid) token as if the `Service` had waited for the `Intent` to complete.

The problem that I can see with this approach involves the user bringing back the parent app without first terminating the authorization `Intent`. I haven't yet tested that case, but would suspect that a lot depends on how `getAuthToken(...)` determines when to return an `Intent`.

Anyway, that's what I've got. Any other suggestions/concerns would be welcomed.